# How to use array of ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to create an array with a `ForEach` loop.

Something like this :

```
let a = [
    ForEach(b) { c in
         "create the element in the array"
    }
]
```

Here is the code I tried :

```
let places = [
    ForEach(viewModel.posts) { post in
        Place(latitude: post.location.latitude, longitude: post.location.longitude)
    }
]
```

But I have an error :

```
Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'Place' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: `ForEach` (with a capital `F`) is for use in a SwiftUI view hierarchy. Even the regular `forEach` doesn't look like a good fit for what I think you might be trying to do, though. Perhaps `map` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jnpdx said, you can use the `map(...)` method of `Array` to accomplish your goal:

```swift
let places: [Place] = viewModel.posts.map { post in
  Place(latitude: post.location.latitude, longitude: post.location.longitude)
}
```